# Doing math to a list in python

Tags: python, list

How do I, say, take `[111, 222, 333]` and multiply it by 3 to get `[333, 666, 999]`?

Comment: You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions). You might also take a look at [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
[3*x for x in [111, 222, 333]]
```

Answer (score 24):

If you're going to be doing lots of array operations, then you will probably find it useful to install [Numpy](https://numpy.org/). Then you can use ordinary arithmetic operations element-wise on arrays, and there are lots of useful functions for computing with arrays.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([111,222,333])
>>> a * 3
array([333, 666, 999])
>>> a + 7
array([118, 229, 340])
>>> numpy.dot(a, a)
172494
>>> numpy.mean(a), numpy.std(a)
(222.0, 90.631120482977593)
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you can use the map command as in the following:

```
map(lambda x: 3*x, [111, 222, 333])
```

Pretty handy if you have a more complex function to apply to a sequence.

Comment: This just returns a <map object at...> some memory pointer, how do you actually get the data from it?

Comment: @george this probably doesn't apply anymore, but if it helps anyone else: `map` and `list` are two different datatypes (I think this became explicitly the case in python 3.x) to turn a `map` into a `list`, simply use the `list()` function. So the example above would become `list(map(lambda x: 3*x, [111, 222, 333]))`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with the use of a map:

```
def multiply(a):
   return a * 3

s = list(map(multiply,[111,222,333]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy set of functions to perform several basic operations on lists. It uses the 'Listoper' class from the listfun module that can be installed through pip.
The appropriate function for your case would be:
"listscale(a,b): Returns list of the product of scalar "a" with list "b" if "a" is scalar, or other way around"
Code:

```
!pip install listfun
from listfun import Listoper as lst
x=lst.listscale(3,[111,222,333])
print(x)
```

Output:

```
[333, 666, 999]
```

Of course if it is just a one time operation you could just do a list comprehension as suggested by others, but if you need to perform several list operations, then the listfun might help.

Hope this helps

Link to the PypI: https://pypi.org/project/listfun/1.0/
Documentation with example code can be found in the Readme file at: https://github.com/kgraghav/Listfun