# Changing all items in a list at once

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a simple "Particle in a box" in Python, where multiple particles are bouncing back and forth between boundaries.
I need to keep track of the x-pos and y-pos of the particle and the x- and y-components of the speed to plot these at the end.

By each dt, the program will calculate the new position. Instead of looping through each particle, I want to update the entire list at once. Otherwise, the calculation and replacements will take forever for more particles.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425336/change-multiple-items-in-a-list-at-one-time-in-python) is already asked. However, I calculate each value each step. This is different from changing an item to a predetermined value.

So, how do I replace each item at once in a list after calculating the new value?

```
dt = 0.001
pos_x = []
pos_y = []
speed_x = []
speed_y = []
```

For-loop to set the speed of each particle:

```
for i in range(5):
    alpha = random.random() * 360
    speed = 0.1 * random.random() * alpha
    speed_x.append(math.sin(speed))
    speed_y.append(math.cos(speed))
    pos_x.append(0.25)
    pos_y.append(0.75)
```

For-loop to update the position of each particle:

```
for n in range(5):
    pos_x[n] = pos_x[n] + speed_x[n] * dt
    pos_y[n] = pos_y[n] + speed_y[n] * dt
```

After this, I will plot all the points and update the window each pause to let them move.

Comment: So, by creating the lists for the speed and place, you can transform these lists into numpy arrays.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of [Doing math to a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645357/doing-math-to-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

   pos = np.array([5,5,5,5,5])
   speed = np.array([2,2,2,2,2])

   new_pos = pos + speed * 0.01
   print(new_pos)
```

Output:

> [5.02 5.02 5.02 5.02 5.02]

With the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) package you can easily add arrays together or multiply them with predefined values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After a of rewriting and learning about numpy arrays, I got it working.